# OnMouseOver start loop, OnMouseOut kill loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I created this little function that loops through images when you go mouse over:

```
            function THUMB_ROLL(NEXT)
            {
                LENGTH = ALL_IMAGES.length;

                if(!LENGTH) { return false; }
                if(!NEXT || NEXT === LENGTH) { NEXT = 0 }

                $('#IMAGE_THUMB').css('background-image','url(/<?php echo $ITEM_CODE;?>/'+ALL_IMAGES[NEXT]+')');

                setTimeout(function() 
                {
                    THUMB_ROLL(NEXT+2)
                },800);
            }

        </script>
```

I have, onmouseover="THUMB_ROLL();"

But, I cannot seem to find a solution to stop the loop once onmouseout. Any help appreciated!

### EDIT

```
<script>

            var timer;

            function THUMB_ROLL(NEXT)
            {
                LENGTH = ALL_IMAGES.length;

                if(!LENGTH) { return false; }
                if(!NEXT || NEXT === LENGTH) { NEXT = 0 }

                $('#IMAGE_THUMB').css('background-image','url(/<?php echo $ITEM_CODE;?>/'+ALL_IMAGES[NEXT]+')');

                timer = setTimeout(function() 
                {
                    THUMB_ROLL(NEXT+1)
                },800);
            }

            $(document).on('mouseover','#IMAGE_THUMB',function()
            {
                THUMB_ROLL();
            });

            $(document).on('mouseout','#IMAGE_THUMB',function()
            {
                clearTimeout(timer);
            });

        </script>
```

Comment: You can't stop a function, you have to create another function that somehow stops the recurence.

Answer (score 1):

Assign your timeout to a variable which store the timerID.

Then have the moueout clear the timeout, which should stop the flow.

```
var timer;

// mouseover event..


timer = setTimeout(function() {
            THUMB_ROLL(NEXT+2)
        },800);

// mouseout event

clearTimeout(timer);
```

Also it is a better idea to separate your concerns and attach the events inside the script tags instead of attaching them inline.

Comment: I did what you said. Under the EDIT portion above. What did I do wrong? It only goes through to the next image and stops.